# How to set up Electron with React and TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, webpack, electron

I'm coding an app with Electron, React (jsx) with Babel. I switched to TypeScript this evening and I can't figure out how to make everything work. Npm packets set up either React or TypeScript, but not both, and not with Electron. (I also have to implement webpack.)

My question is: what is the *minimal* structure of folders, files and packets to make everything work? I just want to display a hello world on the main window using a React component written in TypeScript.
Currently, my packets are Electron, React, ReactDOM, TypeScript.

Comment: There's a lot of different answers to that question. You're better off using a simple scaffolding that already uses these dependencies with sensible defaults. There's a few of those around. [This one](https://medium.com/@paulirwin/getting-started-with-electron-and-visual-studio-code-typescript-and-react-36d41b68fadb) seems to be a good example, as long as you ignore `typings` and use `@types/` instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all i followed this tutorial on the official Website of Typescript: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html

If you follow every step you will end up with a dist folder that contains a bundle.js (with the bundled code that Webpack receives from Typescript) and a src folder that containes the .tsx files. Typescript supports React out of the box, just add `"jsx": "react"` to the tsconfig.json and renane your file `.tsx` instead of `.ts`. After that add index.js to the root folder(copied from here: https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start/blob/master/main.js).

Install electron locally `npm install electron --save-dev` or globally `npm install -g electron`

Run webpack with `webpack` while in the app folder (to generate the ./dist/bundle.js file)

Run electron with `electron .` while in the app folder

The important thing to notice is the entry point of webpack: its ./src/index.tsx while electron entry point is ./index.js. Electron load index.js that loads index.html that loads ./dist/bundle.js. We can transtale index.js to index.ts but then we would have to change the entry point of webpack.

Answer (score 2):

I made a boiler plate starter pack which contains many bug fixes that are found when using react with electron and typescript and has auto monitoring of typescript changes to reload the electron app for faster development.

https://github.com/nateshmbhat/electron-react-ts-starter/

It works with create-react-app without need for ejecting anything.